# Function that calculates the 80th percentile for a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, function, pandas

I'm working with a pandas DataFrame similar to the one below.

---

```
   School  students
0   A       44
1   B       38
2   C       33
3   D       29
4   E       28
5   F       25
6   G       23
```

---

I've created a function that's intended to iterate through each row and accumulate the number of students across school until the sum is greater or equal to 75% of all students. Then the function should return the index of the dataframe. (The column is already sorted.)  My code below isn't working. Can you tell me what is wrong? The error message is below it.

---

```
percentile = .75

def get_top(df,perc=percentile):
    thresh = perc*df['students'].sum()
    cum = 0
    for index, row in df.iterrows() :
        cum = cum + row['students']
        if cum >= thresh:
            return index-1
            break

output = df.apply(get_top)
```

---

KeyError: ('students', u'occurred at index School')

Comment: I think the error is because `apply` applies your function to each column. Your function returns an integer (the index) so when it tries to do it on text data (the `School` column), it fails.

Comment: @Jarad, that's correct. I needed to change the function call from :
    output = df.apply(get_top)
to:
    output = get_top(df,perc=percentile)

jezrael, thank you for sharing the cumsum() function with me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
print (0.75*df['students'].sum())
165.0

print (df.students.cumsum())
0     44
1     82
2    115
3    144
4    172
5    197
6    220
Name: students, dtype: int64

df['out'] = np.where(df.students.cumsum() >= 0.75*df['students'].sum(), 
                    df.index, 
                    df.students.cumsum())
print (df)
  School  students  out
0      A        44   44
1      B        38   82
2      C        33  115
3      D        29  144
4      E        28    4
5      F        25    5
6      G        23    6
```

Or if you want use `percentile` - function [`quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.quantile.html):

```
print (df.students.quantile(.75))
35.5

df['out'] = np.where(df.students >= df.students.quantile(.75), 
                    df.students.cumsum(), 
                    df.index)
print (df)
  School  students  out
0      A        44   44
1      B        38   82
2      C        33    2
3      D        29    3
4      E        28    4
5      F        25    5
6      G        23    6
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jarad indicated in the comment section, I needed to change the function call to:

---

```
output = get_top(df,perc=percentile)
```